# Busca no banco de dados com select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um site para exibição de vídeos cadastrados, para isto fiz com um select para selecionar a disciplina desejada do usuário. Logo após coloquei um botão para exibir estes vídeos cadastrados puxando do MYSQL (com base na disciplina selecionada).

**Como posso fazer para pegar o id do select e buscar, com base neste id da disciplina selecionada, os vídeos enviados?**

Tenho uma parte de um código anterior, porém foi utilizado para identificar o usuário logado, possa servir de base para a resolução do problema.

Código de pesquisa no mysql:

```
   <?php

    $disciplina = $_SESSION['disciplina_prof'];
    $servidor = 'localhost';
    $usuario  = 'root';
    $senha    = 'root';
    $banco    = 'onteach';
    $conexao  = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

    $consulta = "SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    video_monitor
                WHERE
                    video_monitor.disciplina     = '$disciplina'
                    AND video_monitor.pendente = 1";

    $resultados       = mysqli_query($conexao, $consulta);
    $videos_pendentes = array();

    while ($video = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados))
        $videos_pendentes[] = $video;

    mysqli_free_result($resultados);
    mysqli_close($conexao);

    $videos_pendentes = json_encode($videos_pendentes);

?>
```

Código script para selecionar os dados que irão aparecer no carousel: (modificar para o **ID DA DISCIPLINA**, sendo 1 para "Física", 2 para "Matemática")
O select dessa disciplina consta em html assim:

```
<div class="box">
                        <select name="disciplina_prof" id="disciplina_prof">
                          <option value="" selected=selected>Selecione uma disciplina</option>
                          <?php
                          if($num_logar > 0) {
                              do {
                              echo "<option value='".$fet_logar['disciplina_id']."'>".$fet_logar['disciplina_nome']."</option>";
                              }while($fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar));
                          }
                          ?>          
                        </select>
                        <?php print_r($consulta);?>
                      </div>
```

Um exemplo que após o mysql selecionar a disciplina estes, seriam exibidos em carousel:

```
 $('#btn-lista-videos-carousel').click(function() {
            let itens       = '';
            let indicadores = '';

            if (videos_pendentes.length > 0) {

                videos_pendentes.forEach(function(video, indice) {
                    indicadores += '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="' + indice + '" class="' + (indice == 0? 'active' : '') + '"></li>'

                    itens += '<div class="carousel-item ' + (indice == 0? 'active' : '') + '">';
                    itens += '    <iframe  width="100%" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ video.link_video +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' 
                    itens += '</div>';

                });

                console.log(indicadores);

                $('#carouselExampleIndicators').show();
                $('#carousel-indicadores').html( indicadores );
                $('#carousel-itens').html( itens );

            } else {

                alert('Nenhum vídeo pendente');

            }
        });


        $('.carousel').carousel();

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Provavelmente a tabela deve ter um campo `id`, basta chamar esse campo na consulta também

Comment: Você precisa melhorar a forma que está expondo o problema... Para fazer isso de forma dinâmica é necessário o Ajax, mas primeiro você deve pegar o `id`... Então qual é o problema em questão, pegar o `id` ou fazer ou Ajax?

Comment: Você não podem ficar mudando a pergunta a não ser para melhorar detalhes, quando você invalida respostas dadas a pergunta era ruim e a solução não é fazer outra.

Comment: Por isso tem que caprichar nas postagens, o sistema pune repetidas perguntas ruins. Havia uma sinalização sua que a resposta não valia mais para a pergunta e não parece ser a mesma pergunta.

Comment: @Matheus Você precisa fazer uma chamada Ajax baseada no select, tem vários exemplos no site dá uma pesquisada

Comment: @Matheus não pule etapas, caso contrário você ficará preso em um loop de copiar e colar códigos que nunca o levarão ao seu destino conscientemente. Pare um pouco seu código e entenda o fundamento de como a tecnologia Ajax funciona para você poder implementá-la no seu código.

Comment: Matheus@ e ai mano já conseguiu resolver o problema ?

Comment: @MichaelCosta ainda não :(

Comment: @Matheus, nesse momento, qual é o problema ? ta dando erro ?

Comment: até onde entendi, você quer que a pessoa selecione no select qual disciplina ela quer ver, depois disso, você quer um botão pra enviar a disciplina escolhida do select pra armazenar no seu session['disciplina_prof']; é isso ?

Comment: Seria isso mesmo @MichaelCosta

Comment: Porém vou editar para colocar o select da disciplina para você

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106800/discussion-between-matheus-and-michaelcosta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mano, pelo que entendi, você não precisa fazer essas duas ações. você pode fazer assim. usando um select que envia direto pro session quando selecionado.
acho que é oque você ta querendo

essa parte php, você vai receber os dados na própria página.

```
$_SESSION['disciplina_prof'] = '';

if(isset($_GET['disciplina']))
{
    $_SESSION['disciplina_prof'] = $_GET['disciplina'];
    $disciplina = $_SESSION['disciplina_prof'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['disciplina_prof'] = '';
    $disciplina = $_SESSION['disciplina_prof'];
}

$selected = function($check) {
if($_SESSION["disciplina_prof"] == $check) {
return 'selected';
}
};

?>
```

**exemplo de uso:**

```
<select name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
 <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['disciplina_prof'] == 0)  ? 'selected' : '' ; ?> value="index.php?disciplina=null"></option>
 <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['disciplina_prof'] == 1)  ? 'selected' : '' ; ?> value="index.php?disciplina=1">Física</option>
 <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['disciplina_prof'] == 2)  ? 'selected' : '' ; ?> value="index.php?disciplina=2">Matemática</option>
</select>
```

**adaptado para seu código do select.**

```
<select name="disciplina_prof" id="disciplina_prof" onchange="location = this.value;">
    <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['disciplina_prof'] == 0)  ? 'selected' : '' ; ?> value="professor.php?disciplina=null">Selecione uma disciplina</option>
    <?php
    if($num_logar > 0) {
        do {
        echo "<option ". $selected($fet_logar['disciplina_id']) ." value=professor.php?disciplina=".$fet_logar['disciplina_id'].">".$fet_logar['disciplina_nome']."</option>";
        }while($fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar));
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Tem uma pequena alteração amigo, estas disciplinas, não poderão ser pre selecionadas, como na pergunta acima, ela puxa pelo mysql. De uma olhada ali, como poderia alterar para ir automática?

Comment: pronto adaptei no seu código. e agora resolveu ?

Comment: As disciplinas que apareciam do mysql não aparecem mais. Dê uma olhada nessa print: https://prnt.sc/s0th0s

Answer (score 0):

OLá, neste ponto onde você diz:

> Estou desenvolvendo um site para exibição de vídeos cadastrados, para
>   isto fiz com um select para selecionar **a disciplina desejada do
>   usuário**.

Eu estou vendo a consulta da tabela vídeo_monitor, mais está faltando a consulta a tabela de usuário já que você quer mostrar as informações referente ao usuário;

exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM video_monitor a
inner join usuario b on a.usuarioid = b.ID
WHERE video_monitor.disciplina = '$disciplina'
AND video_monitor.pendente = 1
AND B.ID = 1
```

Comment: @Matheus, " posso fazer para pegar o id do select"  dentro do seu $resultados, você tem todos os campos da tabela, você pode pegar o Id retornando na consulta

Comment: na consulta já vai trazer tudo que precisa, pega o conteudo do $resultados e veja

Comment: editei a pergunta, se puder dar uma olhada

Comment: Enfim, quero mostrar as informações referentes a disciplina selecionado no select. Ali no começo do código, como exemplo    $disciplina = $_SESSION['disciplina_prof'];